# Getting Error when creating trigger in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a trigger that will insert a value in the column (work_days) after information is inserted in the rest of the table (vacation_days).

vacation_days:

```
id    name      hire      work_days
1     Josh    20120512      NULL
2     Mark    20130323      NULL
3     John    20151120      NULL
```

Work_days represents the number of days an employee has worked since he/she was hired.

I have tried using a view, however, it doesn't meet my needs as I have to populate other values after work_days is updated.

This is the trigger I have so far:

```
create trigger t_vacation_days before insert on vacation_days for each row    
if NEW.hire>0 THEN SET NEW.work_days:= DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(hire)); END   
IF;//
```

I keep getting this error:

```
1419 (HY000): You do not have SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled   
(you might want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_...)
```

Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks